# jQuery cant load xml from server

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to load the National weather service xml document for my local conditions. I can't seem to successfully load the file from their servers, but if I save the file locally, it works.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KROC.xml', 
        datatype: 'xml' })
            .done(function(data) { alert("Server: success"); })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Server: error:"+jqXHR.statusText+' textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown ); })
            .always(function() { alert("Server: complete"); });
```

That one gives this for an error alert:

> Server: error:error textStatus=error, errorThrown=

But if I save the file locally like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'xml/KROC.xml', 
        datatype: 'xml' })
            .done(function(data) { alert("Client: success"); })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Client: error:"+jqXHR.statusText+' textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown ); })
            .always(function() { alert("Client: complete"); });
```

Then it loads successfully. It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This approach must first tackle a basic limitation of the XMLHttpRequest object used by Ajax programs: the same domain problem.

For security reasons, an XMLHttpRequest call can only initiate requests to the same server that delivered the original Web page. Unless I work for the National Weather Service, my server is outside of their domain (www.nws.noaa.gov).

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlajaxpt1/index.html